# How to Transfer the "Common" Columns between Two CSV Files

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, pandas, dictionary

I am fairly new to programming and want to code this program that transfer the common columns between `file1.csv` and `file2.csv`

**Input:**

`file1.csv` looks like this:

```
ID,Nickname,Gender,SubjectPrefix,SubjectFirstName,Whatever1A,Whaterver2A,SubjectLastName
1,J.,M,Dr.,Jason,,,Allan
2,B.,M,Mr.,Brian,,,Welch
```

`file2.csv` looks like this:

```
nickname,gender,city,id,prefix_name,first_name,Whatever1B,last_name,Whatever2B,Whatever3B,Whatever4B
```

**Problem:**

How to compare the header of `file1.csv` and `file1.csv` to identify and then transfer the "common" columns between them.  The "common" columns are the ones that have similar naming convention, (i.e. `ID` and `id` **,** `Nickname` and `nickname`), or the ones that do not necessarily have the same naming convention, but do store the same data, (i.e. `SubjectPrefix` and `prefix_name` **,** `SubjectFirstName` and `first_name`).

**Output:**

The output should be like this.

- **Note:** the transferred columns `"id"`,`"nickname"`, and `"gender"` are the ones with similar naming between `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` headers.  And the columns `"prefix_name"` and `"first_name"` are the corresponding to `"SubjectPrefix"` and `"SubjectFirstName"`, respectively.

  ```
  id,nickname,gender,prefix_name,first_name,last_name  
  1,J.,M,Dr.,Jason,Allan
  2,B.,M,Mr.,Brian,Welch
  ```

I tried this code:

```
import csv
import collections

csv_file1 = "file1.csv"
csv_file2 = "file2.csv"

data1 = list(csv.reader(file(csv_file1,'r')))
data2 = list(csv.reader(file(csv_file2,'r')))

file1_header = data1[0][:] #get the header from file1
file2_header = data2[0][:] #get the header from file2
lowered_file1_header = [item.lower() for item in file1_header] #lowercase file1 header
lowered_file2_header = [item.lower() for item in file2_header] #lowercase file2 header anyways
col_index_dict = {}

for column in lowered_file1_header:
    if column == "subjectprefix":  # identify "subjectprefix" column in file1.csv
        col_index_dict[column] = lowered_file1_header.index(column)

   elif column == "subjectfirstname": # identify "subjectfirstname" column in file1.csv
        col_index_dict[column] = lowered_file1_header.index(column)

   elif column in file2_header: # identify the columns with same naming
        col_index_dict[column] = lowered_file1_header.index(column)

   else:
        col_index_dict[column] = -1 # mark the not matching columns

# Build header
output = [col_index_dict.keys()]
is_header = True

for row in data1:
    if is_header is False:
        rowData = []
        for column in col_index_dict:
            column_index = col_index_dict[column]
            if column_index != -1:
                rowData.append(row[column_index])
            else:
                rowData.append('')
        output.append(rowData)
    else:
        is_header = False

print(output)
```

Any idea how how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks [Wboy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172342/how-to-transfer-the-common-columns-between-two-csv-files) for your contribution,  your input was really useful.

I was able to find a solution to the problem using Pandas library.  Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

# read the csv files
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

# lowercase the headers
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.lower()

df_columns = set(list(df.columns))
df2_columns = set(list(df2.columns))
```

**Identify and transfer the "common" columns :**

```
for col in list(df_columns):
    for col2 in list(df2_columns):
        if col == "subjectprefix" and col2 =="prefix_name":
            # copy the data from df["subjectprefix"] column to df2["prefix_name"] column in df2 dataframe
            df2["prefix_name"] = df['subjectprefix']
            df3 = [col2]
        elif col == "subjectfirstname" and col2 =="first_name":
            # copy the data from "subjectfirstname" column to "first_name" column
            df2["first_name"] = df["subjectfirstname"]
            df3.append(col2)

        elif col =="subjectlastname" and col2 =="last_name":
            #copy the data from "subjectfirstname" column to "last_name" column
            df2["last_name"] = df["subjectlastname"]
            df3.append(col2)

        elif col == col2:
            # copy the exactly matching to df2
            df2[col2] = df[col]
            df3.append(col2)
```

**Delete the "uncommon" columns from the dataframe df2 :**

```
for col2 in list(df2_columns):
if not col2 in df3:
    del df2[col2]

# print the output
df2.set_index("id",inplace=True)
print df2
```

**Save the output as .csv file :**

```
df2.to_csv('output.csv')
```

I am sure this is not an optimal solution and I hope the code could be improved in terms of identifying and transferring the "common" columns.  My code is full with if/elif statements, and I am sure there must be a better approach to implement here.

Comment: Here look through this for ideas... set(list(x) is not needed ... learn about pandas filtering with "isin".  https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/IntroductionToPythonSolutions.html

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to programming. Let me introduce you to the amazing [pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Off the top of my head, here's something that will solve your problem. (I'm not saying its efficient! So for large datasets it might be a problem)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_Csv('file2.csv')

df_columns = set(list(df.columns))
df2_columns = set(list(df2.columns))

common_columns = list(df_columns.intersection(df2_columns))

common_df = df[common_columns]
common_df2 = df2[common_colmns]

## At this point you have the common columns for both CSV's. if you want
## to make them into one, just use df concatenate / append. else, you can save both of them like this:

common_df.to_csv('common1.csv')
common_df2.to_csv('common2.csv')
```